# Use iMessage textfield in my app instead custom Textfield

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to use the iMessage input field in my app what I mean is this field:
[image: ![image|614x126](upload://AgF9LWCCnnU1IIbSQNaUjWeo8ty.png)]

Does apple provide such as UI or do I need to build by my own.

Comment: Create your own

Answer (score 0):

I made the `TextField()` for anyone else who wants it:

```swift
TextField(" iMessage", text: $text)
    .frame(width: 200)
    .padding(3)
    .overlay(Capsule().stroke(.gray, lineWidth: 1))
    .overlay {
        Image(systemName: "mic.fill")
            .frame(width: 195, alignment: .trailing)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
```